# Example of a divergent power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I was studying Prof. S. Kumaresan's book a pathway to complex analysis where I encountered the following problem.
If $a_n$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers and $R>0$ such that $\sum a_nR^n$ is convergent then show that $\sum a_nz^n$ convergent for each complex number $z$ with $\lvert z \rvert<R$.
I was able to prove this part using comparison test and results on absolute convergence.

The next part asks to show that the result does not hold if the condition $a_n\geq 0$ is relaxed.

I am unable to construct a counter example here. Any hint in that direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no counter-example. Suppose that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nR^n$ converges. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nR^n=0$, and therefore the set $\{a_nR^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is bounded. Let $M>0$ be such that $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z_+):|a_n|R^n \leqslant M$. Then, if $|z|<R$,$$|a_nz^n|=|a_n|R^n\left|\frac zR\right|^n\leqslant M\left|\frac zR\right|^n$$and therefore, since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\frac zR\right|^n$ converges, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Thank you.  I was doubtful whether this question was correctly posed. However, I was missing the point you mentioned.